# How to have a list of random numbers by ensuring all of them at least once used?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, range

I am trying to have a list of numbers from 1 to 10 with many occurrences, therefore I began with using the following code:

```
list(range(1,11))
```

However, it only gives every number only once. I need to have an output in double size, half of it having the arbitrarily ordered numbers and half should have random numbers in the given range like following:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3,4,2,7,5,7,5,2,8,9]
```

My approach was:

1) Making a random list

```
a = random.randint(0,9)
```

2) Combining with the output of range

```
b = list(range(1,11))
result = a+b
```

Is it possible to have it in other way?

Comment: Check my edit if you want the elements in the second half to only be the first half but shuffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `random` built-in.

```
import random

my_list = list(range(1,11))
for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(random.randint(0, 10))

print(my_list)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 5, 10, 8, 6, 10, 6, 5, 6, 6]
```

Comment: @Shiva you can with some changes; OP's example repeats numbers and not all numbers occur at least once, though.

Comment: @Shiva I'm sorry, but did you properly read the question? OP says "half of it having the arbitrarily ordered numbers and half should have random numbers in the given range".

Comment: Keep in mind that `random.randint(0, 10)` will return an integer from 0 to 10 (inclusive). From the question, it appears that the OP needs integers in range 1-10, inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

l = [x for x in range(11)] + [random.randint(0, 10) for x in range(11)]
```

edit 
If you would like the 2nd half of list to only contain elements from the first half, but in a random order

```
a = [x for x in range(11)]
b = a[:]
random.shuffle(b)
a.extend(b)

>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 7, 4, 10, 1, 5, 9, 3, 0, 6, 2, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
import random

your_array = list(range(1, 11)) + random.sample(range(1, 11), 10)  
#  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 7, 8, 2, 1, 9, 5, 10, 6, 4]
```

On a second read... If you want repeats in your second part you can do it as:

```
your_array = list(range(1, 11)) + [random.randrange(1, 11) for _ in range(10)]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 4, 8, 1, 5, 1, 10, 5, 2, 10]
```

Comment: @Shiva why should he? OP wanted the first part to maintain order

Comment: @Shiva titles might be misleading. seen that more than once.